# How to make a navigation call from actions file

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

How can I trigger navigation from actions file when using react-navigation v5 and redux inside my react-native app? Is there any preferable way on how to do this? When result is fulfilled I want to trigger the navigation to the next screen, but I can't use useNavigation(). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a ref to the NavigationContainer

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './path/to/RootNavigation.js';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Create a module RootNavigation.js to hold the ref

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

Now trigger navigation from any place using below:

```
import * as RootNavigation from './path/to/RootNavigation.js';

//...

RootNavigation.navigate('ChatScreen', { userName: 'Lucy' });
```

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Comment: Can I find somewhere version with typescript?

Comment: I was also looking for the same solution. The answer helped me. Thank you (y)

Answer (score 0):

Would this question help you? It seems that it was made by someone trying to accomplish a similar scenario to yours

[React-Navigation: navigate from actions file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765917/react-navigation-navigate-from-actions-file)